# How to get number from String using regex in Groovy

Tags: regex, json, groovy

How can I get number 836481 from String `argString` using regex in groovy ?

```
def argString = '[{"context":"sale","id":836481}]'
```

Comment: `\d+` will give you the number..

Comment: argString .findAll( /\d+/ )*.toInteger() worked for me

Comment: @HarpreetSinghBhullar until one of your other keys or values contains a numeric character, then you're stuck

Comment: I just needed a solution to extract all numeric values from the string and just need the right answer to get numeric values from a string

Comment: @HarpreetSinghBhullar use it only if your string does not have other numbers

Answer (score 5):

Why not parse it as json, seeing as how it's json formatted data?

```
def num = new groovy.json.JsonSlurper().parseText(argString)
                                       .head()
                                       .id
```

Answer (score 4):

I would not use regex to parse json but instead a special purpose json parser. Luckily groovy has one included:

```
import groovy.json.JsonSlurper

def argString = '[{"context":"sale","id":836481}]'
def slurper = new JsonSlurper()
def result = slurper.parseText(argString)
print result[0].id
```

https://groovyconsole.appspot.com/script/5645056174194688

Comment: Thanks your solution also works, but I was looking for regex solution.

Comment: @HarpreetSinghBhullar why? A regex solution to this problem feels the wrong way to go

Comment: Following String def argString = '[{"context":"sale","id":836481}]' was having single numeric value and I was looking for simple, nicer and clear regex solution.

Comment: @HarpreetSinghBhullar you forgot "brittle"